# Correct way to install in to virtual environment (django-import-export package)

Tags: django, virtualenv

I am deploying my site - I have it mostly set up but I notice that when I pip install some of the packages they don't seem to have installed correctly - for instance:

django-import-export Package

- CORRECT WAY - Resulting directory installed locally to C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages w/ no problem:

django_import_export-0.5.1.dist-info

- INCORRECT WAY? - when installed in to virtualenv - the resulting directory is

django_import_export-0.5.1-py3.4.egg-info

Another package - openpyxl did this as well

openpyxl-2.4.7-py3.4.egg-info

What - if anything -  am I doing wrong?

Note that other packages installed w/ pip in to the virtualenv work just fine (psycopg2 for instance)

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you activated the virtualenv and then tried installing using pip?

and what i see it is correct. the info files stays like that, but the python files goes to site packages.

by d way are those packages working or not?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes I activated virtualenv when installing using pip. The django-import-export package does not seem to be working which is what prompted me to ask the question. Based on your answer I will look in to this further today.

Comment: You are correct - the packages did install correctly - I just wanted to make sure because they install differently. Thanks again